# Mocked object returns NPE

Tags: java, testing, mocking, mockito

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class EmpCompSTest {
    @Mock
    private CompCl compCl; 

    @Test
    public void testGetEmpCompS() {
        EmpRequest request = new EmpRequest();
        Map<Long, List<CompCl.CompeSc>> comp = new HashMap<>();
        CompCl.CompSc compSc1
                = new CompCl.CompSc(); 
        comp.put(1L, Arrays.asList(compSc1));
     when(compCl.getUsrSc(request.getComp().keySet())).thenReturn(comp); 
    }
}
```

When debugging, an NullPointerException pops up on the line with `when()` and the class `compCL` is `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Is this Junit5 (Jupiter)? In that case use `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)` instead of `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)`.

Comment: This is Junit4)

Comment: and I don't wanna change version of Junit)

Answer (score 0):

Should have been set `Comp` for `EmpRequest`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).